# Unable to execute one PHP file from other using CURL

Tags: php, curl

I need to execute some code present inside one PHP file and this file will invoked from other PHP file using CURL but simply as per my code its not happening like that.

I am explaining my code below.

> test.php:

```
<?php
include('db.php');
$adminUrl1='http://example.com/api/product/test1.php';
$data1 = array("user_id" => 54, "org_ord_id" => 82);
$data_string1 = json_encode($data1);                       
$ch1 = curl_init($adminUrl1); 
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string1);                                                                  
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string1))                                                                       
);
$res = curl_exec($ch1);
$array = json_decode($res, 1);
echo($array);exit;
?>
```

Here I am trying to execute the `test1.php` file which is present inside `api/product/` directory.

> test1.php:

```
include('db.php');
$user_id=$_POST['user_id'];
$order_id=$_POST['org_ord_id'];
echo $user_id.'::::'.$order_id;
```

Here I need to print those post param value those are passed from `test.php` but as per my current code its not printing anything.

Comment: What `curl_exec` returns?

Comment: @daremachine: `print_r($res);` returns only `::::`.

Comment: try post only array curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data); without json encode.

Comment: @daremachine : No same output.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this `'Content-Type: application/json'`, because you need to get values like `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` for `$_POST[...]`.

And put `application/json` to `CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION` for response.

[CURL_OPT DOC](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)